# UnicodeDecode Error: decoding when writing to xls(x) related to non-english characters

Tags: python, excel, scrapy, xlsxwriter

I've exhausted my searches in trying to figure out where to go from here, so would love some advice on possible next steps, or even a better option.

Synopsis: I am using python to scrape results from websites and then writing that data to an xls(x) doc. I chose xls(x) over csv because my csv kept mangling non-english characters upon a save.

I've managed to successfully run this code on english-only pages, but as soon as I hit non-english characters, it throws the following error on the write().

To note, I've also tried `string.decode('utf-8')`, but that throws a "'ascii' codec can't encode character" error.

Question: What do I need to do to properly have these write to an xls(x)? I've been able to do this without issue to CSV, but as I mentioned, saving it mangles the format. Do I need to encode it differently so the write() function transfers it properly?

For the below code, I've imported scrapy, codecs, xlsxwriter (Workbook), and a few others.

```
# set xpaths:
item_1 = 'xpath'
item_2 = 'xpath'
item_3 = 'xpath'
item_4 = 'xpath'
pagination_lookup = {}
results = []

def write_to_excel(list_of_dicts,filename):
    filename = filename + '.xlsx'
    ordered_list = list(set().union(*(d.keys() for d in list_of_dicts))) # OR set up as actual list of keys (e.g. ['Listing Title','Item Price', etc.])

    wb=Workbook(filename)
    ws=wb.add_worksheet("Sheet 1") #or leave it blank, default name is "Sheet 1"

    first_row=0
    for header in ordered_list:
        col=ordered_list.index(header) # to keep order
        ws.write(first_row,col,header) # to write first row/header

    row=1
    for each_dict in list_of_dicts:
        for _key,_value in each_dict.items():
            col=ordered_list.index(_key)
            ws.write(row,col,_value)
        row+=1 #enter the next row
    wb.close()

name = 'Scraper'
# AREA FOR CODE TO GATHER AND SCRAPE URLS (taken out for brevity)

        driver.get(clean_url)
        time.sleep(2)
        selectable_page = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
        ResultsDict = {}
        ResultsDict['item_1'] = selectable_page.xpath(item_1).extract_first().encode('utf-8')
        ResultsDict['item_2'] = selectable_page.xpath(item_2).extract_first().encode('utf-8')
        ResultsDict['item_3'] = selectable_page.xpath(item_3).extract_first().encode('utf-8')
        ResultsDict['item_4'] = selectable_page.xpath(item_4).extract_first().encode('utf-8')

        results.append(ResultsDict)
        print ResultsDict
        write_to_excel(results,'Scraped_results')
```

The code runs aground on this error, which is triggered by a value with any sort of non-english character (e.g. ñ, ô, ä, etc.)

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/name/scraper1/scraper1/spiders/scraped_results.py", line 128,
>   in 
>       write_to_excel(results,'Scraped_results')
>       [...]
>         File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py",
>   line 369, in write
>           data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
>       UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)

Question: What do I need to do to properly have these write to an xls(x)? I've been able to do this without issue to CSV, but as I mentioned, saving it mangles the format. Do I need to encode it differently so the write() function transfers it properly?

Comment: You left out the most important part of the traceback! Which of *your* lines of code produced the error?

Comment: @MarkRansom updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Python 2.x, which helpfully tries to do a `decode` for you when you pass a byte string to something that requires a Unicode string. Unfortunately that hardly ever does the right thing, which is why they removed that ability in Python 3.

You are creating byte strings by using `.encode('utf-8')` in your scraping. Leave it off and pass the Unicode string into `write_to_excel` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

> switch to python 3.6+